# Отправлять картинки, используя sanic

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow, sanic

Пытаюсь прикрутить sanic  в качестве веб-сервера, мне нужно по хттп запросу возвращать предварительно обработанную картинку
делаю следующее:

```
byte_io = BytesIO()
check_quality(quality)
final_img.save(byte_io, media_type.upper(), quality=quality)
byte_io.seek(0)
mime_type = 'image/' + media_type
print('size')
print(size)
return await response.file_stream(final_img, mime_type)
```

file stream возвращает ошибку:
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not Image

Вопрос: как это исправить?
-Спасибо!

Comment: Вы создали объект `bytes_io`, записали в него изображение, а потом вместо байтов в `file_stream` передаете изображение вместо байтов.

Comment: @insolor поменял final_img на bytes_io, вылетело: TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO

Answer (score 0):

Метод `response.file_stream()` принимает путь к файлу на диске, вы не сможете передать в него буфер. Можно бы было использовать обычный `response.stream()`, но вы вряд ли получите от этого выигрыш, так как отдаваемые данные хранятся одним куском в памяти. Так что просто

```
return response.raw(byte_io.getvalue())
```

Comment: Дело в том, что я совсем новенький, можете объяснить, когда ставить  await после return, а когда нет?

Comment: Проще всего просто посмотреть [примеры в документации](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/response.html#streaming). Там `await` стоит только перед `file_stream`.

Comment: Да, это сработало, однако я собирался отдавать данные на запрос, то есть пользователь вводит /getfile/..., а я возвращаю ему в браузер этот файл, после того, как я ввел то, что вы предложили, браузер сразу пошел сохранять картинку

Comment: `response.raw(byte_io.getvalue(), headers={'Content-Type': mime_type, 'Content-Disposition': 'inline'})`

Answer (score 0):

Так, комментарий выше оказался полезен, за исключением того, что в параметр raw надо было передать также content_type, это решило проблему:

```
    return response.raw(byte_io.getbuffer(),content_type='image/jpeg')
```

Спасибо, что остались неравнодушны!

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)